# How can enable Dialogflow API using google cloud API

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, google-developers-console, gpc

How can I enable the dialogflow api automatically, I want to create a dialogflow agent using the api, but get an error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Dialogflow API has not been used in project 79080971371 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=79080971371 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automatically enable APIs in projects on Google developer console.   There are some things in your project that need to be configured by you the developer.

You need to manually go to your project and then go to library and enable the API you are trying to access.  In this case enable dialogflow api

Comment: I see possible to enable the service at this docs: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/enable
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: As far as i know Google cloud services (gRCP services) inst the same thing as Google developer console (rest services).  Its two different systems which allow you to access different things.    I have been trying to find a way to do this for eight years if you do manage to find some way of getting in please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Go api and service click enable dialog flow api. Default it's disabled so we have to enable then restart.